# Node.js: print object graph with cycle detection?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Without writing my own function, is there a method for printing an object graph in Node.js which will do something sensible when it encounters a cycle?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it looks like `console.log` *does* do cycle detection:

```
> var a = {};
> var b = {};
> var c = {};
> a.b = b;
> b.c = c;
> c.a = a;
> console.log(a);
{ b: { c: { a: [Circular] } } }
```

It must be something else that is causing my code to block on `console.log(someSimpleObject)`.